# Akka.Net Clustering Simple Explanation

Tags: cluster-computing, akka.net

I try to do a simple cluster using akka.net.

The goal is to have a server receiving request and akka.net processing it through it cluster.

For testing and learning I create a simple WCF service that receive a math equation and I want to send this equation to be solved.

I have one project server and another client.

The configuration on the server side  is :

```
<![CDATA[
      akka {
            actor {
              provider = "Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster"
              debug {
                receive = on
                autoreceive = on
                lifecycle = on
                event-stream = on
                unhandled = on
              }
              deployment {
                /math {
                  router = consistent-hashing-group #round-robin-pool # routing strategy
                  routees.paths = [ "/user/math" ]
                  virtual-nodes-factor = 8
                  #nr-of-instances = 10 # max number of total routees
                  cluster {
                     enabled = on
                                           max-nr-of-instances-per-node = 2
                                           allow-local-routees = off
                                           use-role = math
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            remote {
                helios.tcp {
                    transport-class = "Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTcpTransport, Akka.Remote"
                                    applied-adapters = []
                                    transport-protocol = tcp
                    port = 8081
                    hostname = "127.0.0.1"
                }
            }
          cluster {
              seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:8081"] # address of seed node
             }

          }
  ]]>
```

On the Client side the configuration is like this :

```
 <![CDATA[
      akka {
            actor.provider = "Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster"
            remote {
                log-remote-lifecycle-events = DEBUG
                log-received-messages = on

                helios.tcp {
                    transport-class = "Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTcpTransport, Akka.Remote"
                                    applied-adapters = []
                                    transport-protocol = tcp
                    port = 0
                    hostname = 127.0.0.1
                }
            }
            cluster {
              seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:8081"] # address of the seed node
              roles = ["math"] # roles this member is in
             }
            actor.deployment {
              /math {
                router = round-robin-pool # routing strategy
                routees.paths = ["/user/math"]
                nr-of-instances = 10 # max number of total routees
                cluster {
                   enabled = on
                   allow-local-routees = on
                   use-role = math
                   max-nr-of-instances-per-node = 10
                }
              }
            }
          }
  ]]>
```

The cluster connection seems to correctly be made. I see the status [UP] and the association with the role "math" that appeared on the server side.

Event follwing the example on the WebCramler, I don't achieved to make a message to be delivered. I always get a deadletters.

I try like this :

```
actor = sys.ActorOf(Props.Empty.WithRouter(FromConfig.Instance), "math");
```

or

```
var actor = sys.ActorSelection("/user/math");
```

Does someone know a good tutorial or could help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks:

First: assuming your sending work from the server to the client. Then you are effectively remote deploying actors on your client.
Which means only the server node needs the `actor.deployment` config section.
The client only needs the default cluster config (and your role setting ofcourse).

Second: Try to make it simpler first. Use a `round-robin-pool` instead. Its much simpler. Try to get that working. And work your way up from there.
This way its easier to eliminate configuration/network/other issues.

Your usage: `actor = sys.ActorOf(Props.Empty.WithRouter(FromConfig.Instance), "math");` is correct.

A sample of how your `round-robin-pool` config could look:

```
deployment {
                /math {
                  router = round-robin-pool # routing strategy
                  nr-of-instances = 10 # max number of total routees
                  cluster {
                     enabled = on
                     max-nr-of-instances-per-node = 2
                     allow-local-routees = off
                     use-role = math
                  }
                }
              }
```

Try this out. And let me know if that helps.

Edit:

Ok after looking at your sample. Some things i changed

- `ActorManager->Process`: Your creating a new router actor per request. Don't do that. Create the router actor once, and reuse the `IActorRef`.
- Got rid of the minimal cluster size settings in the `MathAgentWorker` project
- Since your not using remote actor deployment. I changed the `round-robin-pool` to a `round-robin-group`.

After that it worked.

Also remember that if your using the `consistent-hashing-group` router you need to specify the hashing key. There are various ways to do that, in your sample i think the easiest way would be to wrap the message your sending to your router in a `ConsistentHashableEnvelope`. Check the docs for more information.

Finally the akka deployment sections looked like this:

```
deployment {
                    /math {
                        router = round-robin-group # routing strategy
                        routees.paths = ["/user/math"]
                        cluster {
                           enabled = on
                           allow-local-routees = off
                           use-role = math
                        }
                     }
                  }
```

on the MathAgentWorker i only changed the cluster section which now looks like this:

```
cluster {
                  seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:8081"] # address of the seed node
                  roles = ["math"] # roles this member is in
                 }
```

And the only thing that the `ActorManager.Process` does is:

```
 return await Program.Instance.RouterInstance.Ask<TResult>(msg, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Comment: I try and it doesn't work better. The only way I achieve was to ask to cluster the address of the leader actor for a specific role. But doing this I doesn't not use the deployement neither the router power.

Comment: Edited my answer to share my findings on your sample project. Also. Next time please use a different code sharing mechanism then onedrive.

Comment: Thanks a lot the main problem was round-robin-pool vs round-robin-group